# worklight adapter invoke web service. error Cannot read property Body

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Invoking the following adapter return `Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot read property \"Body\" from undefined.`

I have read similar threads and had

`-Dorg.xml.sax.driver = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser`

to eclipse.ini
but didn't solve the issue.

```
function getStateDetails(idstate) { 
    var request='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
      '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
      +'<soap:Body>'
      + '<test_demo><in0>{idstate}</in0></test_demo>'
      +'</soap:Body>'
      +'</soap:Envelope>';

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '/axis2/services/ws_demo/test_demo.wsdl',
        body : {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };

    var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    return result.Envelope.Body;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally it works fine with the help of soapui and adding headers in the request.

```
function getStateDetails(idstate) {
var request='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
        +'<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
        +'<Body><test_demo xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/informix/i4gl-soa/2010-11/ws_commandes">'
        +'<in0>'+idstate+'</in0></test_demo>'
        +'</Body></Envelope>';

        WL.Logger.debug("SOAP Request " + request);
            var input = {
                method : 'post',
                returnedContentType : 'xml',
                headers: {SOAPAction: 'test_demo'},
                path : '/axis2/services/ws_commandes',
                body : {
                    content: request.toString(),                  
                    contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'                
                }               

            };
            var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);               
            return result.Envelope.Body.test_demo_response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're making a request to the WSDL, not service itself.

Comment: but it doesn't change the issue

Comment: Try changing returnContentType to "plain". You will receive the response in a plain text format, so you can see what is the problem with it.

Comment: now i get <code>{
   "errors": [
      "Premature end of file.",
      "Failed to parse the payload from backend (procedure: HttpRequest)"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      "Date": "Fri Mar 15 16:25:11 2013 GMT",
      "Server": "Axis2C\/1.5.0 (Simple Axis2 HTTP Server)"
   },
   "statusCode": 415,
   "statusReason": "Unsupported Media Type",
   "warnings": [
   ]
}</code>