# Soap Adpter Isssue:Cannot read property "Body" from undefined: WORKLIGHT

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am making a adapter for HTTP soap based invocation, code for invocation is given below while invoking the adapter i am getting error like :"Cannot read property "Body" from undefined" .

**SOAPAdapter.xml is:**

```
<wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="SOAPAdapter">

<displayName>SOAPAdapter</displayName>
<description>SOAPAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>*.*.com</domain>
        <port>80</port>         
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2"/>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="get_soap_req_list"/>
```

**SOAPAdapter-impl.js is:**

function get_soap_req_list() {

```
  var request = 
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
        +'<soap:Body>'
            +'<AddList  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">'
                +'<listName>tiu</listName>'
                +'<description>uyt</description>'
                +'<templateID>6</templateID>'
            +'</AddList>'
        +'</soap:Body>'
    +'</soap:Envelope>';
WL.Logger.debug("@@@"+request);

            var input = {
                method : 'post',
                returnedContentType : 'xml',
                path : '/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx',
                body : {
                    content: request.toString(),                  
                    contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'                
                }               

            };
**27**            var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);               
**28**            return result;
}
```

**console error is:**

E: An error occurred while invoking procedure SOAPAdapter/get_soap_req_listFWLSE0100E:  parameters:{
   "arr": [
      9
   ]
  }
  TypeError: Cannot read property "Body" from undefined   (D%3A%5CWorklightworkSpace%5Cmodule_05_2_HTTP_Adapter%5Cadapters%5CSOAPAdapter/SOAPAdapter-  impl.js#42)
  FWLSE0101E: Caused by: null

**result OutPut:**

{
   "errors": [
    ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Content-Length": "0",
      "Date": "Thu, 20 Jun 2013 11:08:03 GMT",
      "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices": "14.0.0.6123",
      "SPRequestGuid": "7a89adce-9ede-4197-bfc4-aff18e85e763",
      "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/7.5",
      "WWW-Authenticate": "NTLM",
      "X-MS-InvokeApp": "1; RequireReadOnly",
      "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET"
   },
   "responseTime": 156,
   "statusCode": 401,
   "statusReason": "Unauthorized",
   "text": "",
   "totalTime": 172,
   "warnings": [
    ]
    }

Comment: Please see if this question's answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428615/worklight-adapter-invoke-web-service-error-cannot-read-property-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to "return result;"

What is the output?

Comment: execution not goes to result, error is while invoking HTTP Procedure. with error:: E: An error occurred while invoking procedure SOAPAdapter/get_soap_req_listFWLSE0100E:  parameters:{
   "arr": [
   ]
}
TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (D%3A%5CWorklightworkSpace%5Cmodule_05_2_HTTP_Adapter%5Cadapters%5CSOAPAdapter/SOAPAdapter-impl.js#28)
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: null

Comment: Can you paste adapter code with line numbers? Also, change returnedContentType to 'plain' and retry.

Comment: i tried with 'plain'  but the same issue, line 28 is 'return result' , means after invokehttp method if i write ' WL.Logger.debug("#######"+result+"$%%%%");' then the error occurs on that line/ please refer to my edited adapter code

Comment: can you please try  my code(Implement soap adapter) on yours eclipse.please do required change on your soap http adapter.

Comment: You cannot concatenate result with string, it will fail. Change your code to:
WL.Logger.debug("result start ---------");
WL.Logger.debug(result);
WL.Logger.debug("result end --------");

Comment: ok..what should be the return type? if i writes 'return result' then its returns result  however if i writes 'return result.Envelope.Body;' then error is 'TypeError: Cannot read property "Body" from undefined '

Comment: Paste the result you're getting with returnedContentType:'plain'

Comment: I have pasted my 'result OutPut' under question section above, please refer this.

Comment: As you can see in the response your IIS backend requires HTTP authentication (with NTLM). You need to supply header/credentials to use it. You can configure adapter to use NTLM, this is described here - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_the__authentication__element_o.html